# Перевести код с Паскаля на VBA

Tags: pascal, vba

Исходник на Паскале:

```
Procedure Hord(A,B:Real; E:Real; var X, Fx:Real;n:integer); 
  var
   X0,Fa,Fb:real;
Begin
    if dF2(A,n)*F(A,n) > 0 then
    begin
        X:=B;X0:=A;
        Fa:=F(A,n);
        while (Abs(X0-X)>E) do
        begin
           X0:=X;
           Fx:=F(X0,n);
           X:=X0-Fx*(X0-A)/(Fx-Fa);
      end
   end
   else 
   begin
     X:=A;X0:=B;
     Fb:=F(B,n);
     while (Abs(X0-X)>E) do
     begin
          X0:=X;
          Fx:=F(X0,n);
          X:=X0-Fx*(B-X0)/(Fb-Fx);
    end
  end;
  Fx:=F(X,n);
End.
```

---

Попытка решения на VBA:

```
Dim x As Single, x1 As Single, f1 As Single, f2 As Single
Dim n As Integer
Const e = 0.001
Private Function f(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    f = x - 3 - Sin(3 * x)
End Function
Private Function Fd(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Fd = 1 - 3 * Cos(3 * x)
End Function

Private Sub Command3_Click()
'metod hord
    Text3.Text = ""
    x1 = Val(Text1.Text)
    X2 = Val(Text2.Text)
    Do While Abs(x1 - X2) > e
        x3 = X2 - f(X2) * (X2 - x1) / (f(X2) - f(x1))
        x1 = X2
        X2 = x3
        DoEvents
    Loop
Text3.Text = Round(x3, 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: Во, так лучше. Я перенес код из вашего комментария прямо в вопрос. В будущем, чтобы дополнить вопрос, редактируйте его: кнопка [edit].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Окей, вы привели ваш код, это уже хорошо.

Смотрите, современные императивные языки все очень похожи друг на друга, поэтому переводить можно практически построчно. Попробуем? Читайте комментарии, они важны (и я перевёл не весь код).

У меня нет на чём проверить, так что может быть не везде верный синтаксис.

```vb
' Procedure Hord(A,B:Real; E:Real; var X, Fx:Real;n:integer);
' функции, не возвращающие значение, определяются ключевым словом Sub
' обыкновенные параметры - ByVal, var-параметры - ByRef
' Непонятно, зачем вам n, оно по идее нигде не используется, так что я его выкинул
Private Sub Hord(ByVal A As Double, ByVal B As Double, ByVal E As Double, _
      ByRef X As Integer, ByRef Fx as Double, ByVal n as Integer) As Double
  ' var
  '   X0,Fa,Fb:real;
  Dim X0, Fa, Fb As Double
  ' Begin
  ' блоки в VB неявные, begin/end отпадают
  '     if dF2(A,n)*F(A,n) > 0 then
  ' тут проблема, вы, кажется, тут анализируете вторую производную (dF2)?
  ' во-первых, у вас нет такой функции (её можно написать аналогично Fd),
  ' но я не уверен, что это математически правильно.
  If dF2(A) * F(A) > 0 Then
  ' begin
    ' X:=B;X0:=A;
    X = B
    Х0 = A
    ' Fa:=F(A,n);
    Fa = F(A)
    ' while (Abs(X0-X)>E) do
    '    begin
    While Math.Abs(X0-X) > E
      ' X0:=X;
      X0 = X
      ' Fx:=F(X0,n);
      Fx = F(X0)
      ' X:=X0-Fx*(X0-A)/(Fx-Fa);
      X = X0 - Fx * (X0 - A) / (Fx - Fa)
    ' end
    End While
  ' end
  ' else 
  Else
    ' эта часть совершенно аналогична, переведёте сами?
  End If
  ' Fx:=F(X,n);
  Fx = F(X)
' End.
End Sub
```